# Q on plotting function against t and trajectory in phase space(matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot

I am very beginner for matlab and try to solve this question. But so far it is not successful. I have spent quite a time and I think I need some help. I would appreciate any help!!!

I need to plot v against time and trajectory of v and w in phase space. The whole question is below and my code for previous question connected to this question is also below. I can go with subplot(2,1,1) for the first graph and subplot(2,1,2) for the next graph. But I am not sure what I have to do other than this. I kind of found ode45 command. But not sure how to use it and if it is the right one to use here. I have tried to use ode45. But it shows many errors that I don't understand.....Please help me on this. Thanks a lot!

'Create a figure which contains two graphs, using subplot. In the first graph, plot the temporal evolution of the membrane potential v(t) against time t. In the second graph, plot the corresponding trajectory (v(t); w (t)) in (the so-called) phase space.'

```
% my code is below.
a=0.08;
b=3.6;
c=0.7;
T=2; % this can be any number
I_ext=20; % this can be any number
dt=0.01; % this can be any number

function [ v,w ] = fhnn( a,b,c,I_ext,T,dt)
v=zeros(1,numel(T/dt));
w=zeros(1,numel(T/dt));
for n=1:numel(T/dt)
v(n+1)=(v(n)-v(n)^3/3-w(n)+I_ext)*dt+v(n);
w(n+1)=a*(v(n)-b*w(n)+c)*dt+w(n);
end
```

Comment: The function `fhnn` does not have an `end` statement there (which will cause an error), nor is it used... can it just be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I gather you have a differential equation and are trying to directly plot that. You might find a better approach would be to actually solve the equation if that is possible.

Either way, recognising that:

- `numel` returns the length of an array and `dT/dt` is always a scalar so the length is always one.
- `fhnn` is not used here.
- You still need a vector `t`.

If what is in your `for` loop is correct, the following should work:

```
a=0.08; b=3.6; c=0.7; T=2; I_ext=20; dt=0.01;

t = 0:dt:T;
v = zeros(1,round(T/dt));
w = zeros(1,round(T/dt));
for n=1:round(T/dt)-1
    v(n+1)=(v(n)-v(n)^3/3-w(n)+I_ext)*dt+v(n);
    w(n+1)=a*(v(n)-b*w(n)+c)*dt+w(n);
end

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,v)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('v')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(v,w)
xlabel('v')
ylabel('w')
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and correction. I have one question, though. Why did you start the for loop from 2? I am confused with this numbers for for loop whenever I do the integration using Euler or midpoint rule. Thanks again! It was very helpful.

Comment: Ah, my bad. When I do this kind of thing I normally do `v(n) = f(v(n-1))` - to avoid referencing `v(0)` I loop from 2 to the end of the array. In your case, you are doing `v(n+1) = f(v(n))`, so you have to should start from 1 but stop one before the end of the array. I have modified the code to reflect this.